# How to mock Onclose event in Jest?

Tags: angularjs, jestjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to test below code with Jest framework and AngularJS 1.8.

```
 $(".classA").timepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      timeFormat: "hh:mm",
      onClose: function () {
          $scope.varA=1;
      }
 });
```

My jest test case is like below:

```
 describe('when scope.someMethod() is called ', function(){
        test('Should check varA is 1 when scope.someMethod() is called' , function(){
            $.fn.timepicker =  ({}) => {onClose: callback => {callback();}};
            scope.someMethod();
            expect(scope.varA).toEqual(1);
        });
 });
```

But when I debug the test case, the variable is not set. Please provide suggestions.

Edit:

also tried with, but could not solve.

```
  $.fn.timepicker =  jest.fn((obj) => {
                return {
                    onClose: callback => {
                        callback();
                    }
                }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
   $.fn.timepicker =  jest.fn((obj) => {
                return obj.onClose();
                });
```